# Wordpress: Allow shop manager roles to edit plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, roles, user-permissions

I'm trying to modify the user permissions for my Shop Managers on Wordpress Woocommerce so they can use a plugin called [Woocommerce Gift Coupons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gift-coupon/).

I had a look at [this guide](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-user-roles-in-wordpress/#modifyuserrolemanually) on how to use add_caps() to assign user permissions manually, but I'm not sure if I got the right end of the stick on how to use it, or if I'm using it in the right place. I tried addomg the below to my `functions.php` file but obviously this didn't work for me:

```
/* Change Shop Manager Roles */
function shop_manager_add_coupons() {
    $user = get_role('shop_manager');
    $user->add_cap('woocommerce_gift_coupon');
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'shop_manager_add_coupons');
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?